# Script that runs couple of applications, keeps alive and kill all of them on exit

Tags: bash, macos

How can I write bash script that will run few commandline apps in background but will stay alive afterwards (terminal/console blocking). When killed it would kill all started apps.

Is that possible? If not what alternative solution should I consider?
If yes, how to implement that?

At the moment I have this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

command_1 &>/dev/null &

command_2 &>/dev/null &

command_3 &>/dev/null &

fg
```

---

EDIT: It's working now, thanks!

```bsh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

set -eu

trap "kill -9 -- 0" EXIT ERR SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM SIGKILL SIGHUP SIGABRT

sleep 60 &>/dev/null &
sleep 60 &>/dev/null &
sleep 60 &>/dev/null &
sleep 60 &>/dev/null &

while :; do
    :
done
```

Comment: The script should remember PIDs of background processes, you should check `trap` and `nohup` commad.

Comment: @JiriB thanks, I updated post with what I have at the moment

Comment: There are syntax errors in than script. Please send through [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) first.

Comment: @l0b0 thanks, I did but I've got warning that I don't know how to handle `This redirection doesn't have a command. Move to its command (or use 'true' as no-op).`

Comment: It's confused about the syntax. `&` to background the command must come *after* the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (Update based on FelixNj's comment).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

trap "kill -9 -- 0" EXIT ERR
   
sleep 600 &

sleep 600 &

# loop
while :; do
    # do something clever here
    :
done
```

Comment: Use `trap "kill -9 -- -$$" EXIT ERR` where `-$$` stands for the whole process group as defined by the script. As long as one does not disown a process, it should catch them all. Saves you the whole `cleanup` function and storing PIDs. `wait` instead of an infinite sleep might also be preferred - it seems the commands in OP's request never stop.

Comment: @jiri-b looks good thanks, I think it may be missing `-$$` as @felixjn suggested but I may be wrong. I struggle a bit to find information in the manual what `-0` means in the `kill` context. Also I think they may be missing link between `$pids` and `kill` inside `trap` command. Can you explain the purpose of `echo -n .`? thanks!

Comment: IIUC there was a mistake, it should be `kill -9 -- 0`, see `man kill`, ie. '0' is *all processes in the current process group*.

Comment: Ok but how kill would now that pids variable contains group of processes? Is pids required at all?

Comment: @JiriB I saw you edited the script, it make more sense now. I have a question, if it's fine to run sleep for 60 or even more inside while loop here?

Comment: ps. I hope the way `kill` works on macOS is the same as on Linux because documentation is much more brief then the one on Linux. It doesn't mention anything about PID 0.